# Geocoding returns wrong town when applied to dataframe - returns correct one when applied to text

Tags: python, encoding, geocode

I have a silly problem: I am trying to geocode several towns in Germany, the names of the towns are stored in a column in a dataframe. The coding works for all towns except for one: Münster.

My dataframe looks something like this (pasting the interesting part here):

```
68  1034291939  Lüneburg        2010    330       (Lüneburg, Niedersachsen, Deutschland, (53.248...
69  1003394345  Kassel          2010    330       (Kassel, Niestetal, Hessen, Deutschland, (51.3...
70  100975873X  Magdeburg       2010    330.157   (Magdeburg, Sachsen-Anhalt, Deutschland, (52.1...
71  1191280594  Ludwigsburg     2010    340       (Ludwigsburg, Landkreis Ludwigsburg, Baden-Wür...
72  1010526499  Potsdam         2010    338.947   (Potsdam, Brandenburg, Deutschland, (52.400930...
73  1008154156  Duisburg        2010    658.72    (Duisburg, Nordrhein-Westfalen, Deutschland, (...
74  1011028336  Münster         2010    330       (Munster, Éire / Ireland, (52.307621600000004,...
75  1008507016  Jena            2010    338.04    (Jena, Thüringen, Deutschland, (50.9281717, 11...
```

As you can see, there are other town names in the dataframe containing special characters such as "ü" ("Lüneburg") that don't cause any problems, but Münster - for whatever reason - gets geocoded to Munster in Ireland.  For the record, I use the following code to geocode the townname:

`df_geo['geo_code'] = df_short.Ort.apply(geocode)`

I have tried checking if this is a general problem with the database, but if I run
`location = geocode('Münster')` it returns `Münster, Nordrhein-Westfalen, Deutschland` just fine. I am at a total loss now as to why this doesn't work when I apply it to the dataframe. I thought it could be a problem with the ü, but the table I read the data from is encoded in utf-8 and displays the ü correctly when I open it (e.g. in Excel). Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be and how I can fix it? Do I need to encode or decode the data differntly before running the geocoding on the dataframe?

Edit: Edited the dataframe so that the different columns are easier to spot

**Edit2:** To fix this problem, I have now tried extracting the location names and dumping them to a list to then run that list with a loop through the geocoder, but I still have the same issue: all names convert correctly apart from Münster, which always gets coded as Munster, Ireland. I tried the following code:

```
for entry in places: 
    location = geocode(places)
    print(location)
```

In addition, I then tried geocoding the string again and all of sudden Münster turned to Munster as well. Interestlingly enough, I have now found out, that there seems to be difference between using " " for the string vs. ' ':

```
location = geocode("Münster")
print(location)
location2 = geocode('Münster')
print(location2)
```

returns:

```
Munster, Éire / Ireland
Münster, Nordrhein-Westfalen, Deutschland
```

Why is that? So I am now thinking that the problem is that when I use a variable (places), it somehow treats the code as if it were in double quotes  while I need it to treat it as single quote. How can I change that? I suppose converting all the names to strings isn't really going to solve the problem (as they're already strings) and would be unneccessarily complicated...

Comment: Isn't that because 330 is shifted? I mean is it a coincidence? Try maybe to change it position or to modify the coordinates by hand.

Comment: The 330 isn't part of the column that the geocoding uses, it's in a separate column.

Comment: I have now even tried wrapping the string into single quotation marks and while that works while using the string directly, it still doesn't work as soon as I parse it as a variable. I honestly don't understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a lot of trial and error I finally discovered that there was a problem with the underlying encoding. I added the following bit of code and now the geocoding runs though smoothly and translates "Münster" to Münster in Germany.

```
def normalize(text): 
    new = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', text)
    return new 

df_geo['Ort'] = df_geo['Ort'].apply(normalize)

places = df_geo['Ort'].tolist()

for entry in places: 
    location = geocode(entry)
    print(location)
```